# What does 'dither' mean in GRASS GIS?

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.0

What does the -d flag 'Dither' in GRASS GIS mean? For example in [r.composite](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.composite.html)

Comment: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.composite.html

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Steinberg_dithering